# Не работает Ajax.BeginForm в цикле for

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Представление:

```
@model List<Craft.Models.Entity.Work>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div id="form_@i">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditSampleWork","Works",
            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "form_" + i.ToString() }, 
            new { id = "Form_" + i }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].UserCraftId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].UserPriceId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].UserPrice)

            <div class="row">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i].TitleDiscription)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i].Discription)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Price)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].TimeWork)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="btnsave_@i"  value="Сохранить" />
        }
    </div>
}
```

Метод контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditSampleWork(Work model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return PartialView();
    }


    return PartialView("Works", model);
}
```

В контроллере в `model` приходит все `null`.

Comment: Так проблема-то в чем?

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EditSampleWork(Work model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return PartialView();
            }

        
            return PartialView("Works", model);
        }

Comment: в отправленной модели везде null

Comment: Везде null потому, что вы забыли передать модель в представление. Сформулируйте вопрос нормально.

Comment: @AndrewB я предаю в представление список моделей List<Craft.Models.Entity.Work> и хочу реализовать возможность редактировать отдельно каждую

Comment: у Вас в представлении есть ошибка - это `model` и `Model` - нужно исправить. Везде в предикатах используйте уж `model`...как-то Вы и не то и не то используете - это во-первых. А во-вторых - попробуйте еще после этого добавить `name` для формы - это если не поможет исправление букв .